# SSAS - data in three places?

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse

New to DW concepts and SSAS.  I'm reading alot that normalized relational dbs are optimal for OLTP due to a typical workload of many one-transaction batches.  And denormalization is generally better for DW/BI applications because the nature of queries used for reporting are more batch-based...  there were other reasons that I don't recall right now.

It sounds like the advice says to create a denormalized model and populate it from the base relationship model and then build your cubes off the denormalized model.  Assuming you're using MOLAP storage type, your cube will store and incrementally update your data in a multidimensional model that it builds behind the scenes.

So now we have essentially the same data stored three times!

Am I reading that right?  Why do we even need that intermediate denormalized table? It can't be to optimize report queries because those are being run against the multidimensional SSAS data store.   Why not just build your cubes against a dsv whose definition is basically a view of the relational db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multidimensional model needs the relational model to be available in star schemas (that is what you call "denormalized model") for loading the data. And in many cases, there is some processing like combining data from different sources, keeping the data for reporting longer than it is needed in the OLTP world, keeping historical views like old regional or department structures available for analyzing which are not necessary and hence overwritten in the OLTP world. Hence, this intermediate step makes sense in many cases. You might also want to have clear cut of times, i. e. always report data for complete days (or, in some cases, months), and not have some data for the last day available and some not, which makes comparison of numbers for a day easier than comparing e. g. the sales of today containing only the data up to 10 o'clock with the sales of the whole day yesterday.

In some simple cases, the intermediate relational data structure need not be available physically. A few days ago I prepared a prototype cube where the star schema was just a set of views on the source data. In this case, of course, the data was only physically available in the original source form and in the cube. The structure of the source data did not make the views that inefficient, and thus data loading to the cube was fast enough for the prototype.